# How do I change EWS Outlook Calendar Appointment Body's type

Tags: exchangewebservices

I tried to access Outlook Calendar Appointment's Body using EWS Managed Api.Before I access the subject of appointment and its type is string. After I tried to access the body and I accessed.
But it isn't useful for me. Because its type is HTML, so I can't read its values contained in. I can use the type of string or string[] or type like them for read the body's value contained in without html tags. How can I solve this problam.

Answer (score 3):

To get the body of an item in plain-text use this snippet:

```
var contact = Contact.Bind(service, itemId, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties) { RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text});
```

This will instruct the EWS service to return the body as plain text.

Comment: +1  The `PropertySet` can be given at several different places, but the important thing is to set the `RequestedBodyType` property of the `PropertySet` to `BodyType.Text` and to load the body (which is done in the above example as it is part of the `BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties`).